# Debugging Installation Problems with Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web

Tags: windows-7, installation, visual-studio-2013

I'm having 2 strange issues on a fresh install of VS2013 Express for Web. The install ***seemed*** to go ok, but when completed I have two problems.

*Could anybody help or point me in the right direction to either solve or begin debugging this? I am praying against a Windows reinstall, but it's starting to look like the only option.*

**1. Can't Create New Project or New Website**

A new project gives me this alert box:

```
Error loading type library/dll.  
Exception from hresult: 0x80029c4A TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY
```

When attempting a new Web Site, it gives me:

```
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

**2. No exe File in Start Menu**

I don't know if it's related or not, I'm hoping it's a clue.

There is no exe in the start menu. There's a VS 2013 folder, but it's empty.

[image: screenshot of empty start folder]

**What I've Tried - Updated**

- Uninstalling / reinstalling (many times!)
- Installing through WebPI and through direct download from website
- Applying updates from Windows Update
- Then uninstalling and reinstalling again
- Ensured system path is under 2000 chars (it's 600)
- Disabling anti virus when installing
- Ensured .NET Framework is up to date on PC
- Running VS as Administrator
- Installing VS as Administrator

None of these steps seemed to help - all gave me the same result.

Google results for the error messages mostly refer to different circumstances - e.g. somebody trying to integrate a VS app with MS Office.

**Final Update**

I ended up reinstalling Windows - that worked.

Comment: If you downvote, please explain so OP can learn

Comment: Have you tried running VS as Administrator? It looks like the perms might be messed up.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, tried it, but unfortunately I'm still getting the same messages :(

Comment: Hope you have updated all your framework.

Comment: How would I ensure that?  I had thought the latest version of VS and all the MS Updates take care of that, but I could be wrong

Comment: I checked all is up to date.

Comment: @MartinHansenLennox: Did you find the solution for this problem, bro?

Comment: Afraid not... ended up having to reinstall Windows entirely :(